# Funcion de postgres ejecutada desde java

Tags: java, postgresql, funciones

Tengo una función en `PostgreSQL` que toma 6 valores, el primero un character `varying`, el siguiente un entero y los 4 restantes son de tipo `numeric`.
Lo llamo desde Java de la siguiente manera:

```
preStmt=con.prepareStatement("SELECT 
sp_ins_act_productounidad(?,?,?,?,?,?);");
preStmt.setString(1, entPU.getProd_cod());
preStmt.setInt(2, entPU.getUni_codigo());
preStmt.setDouble(3, entPU.getPu_minimo());
preStmt.setDouble(4, entPU.getPu_maximo());
preStmt.setDouble(5, entPU.getPu_precionormal());
preStmt.setDouble(6, entPU.getPu_precioespecial());
rs=preStmt.executeQuery();
```

Me presenta el siguiente error:

> no existe la función sp_ins_act_productounidad(character varying,
>   integer,double precision, double precision, double precision, double
>   precision)
>       Hint: Ninguna función coincide en el nombre y tipos de argumentos. Puede ser necesario agregar conversión explícita de tipos.

Probé la función desde `PostgreSQL` y no me da ningún problema pero al llamarla desde Java me arroja ese error, probé ademas cambiando el tipo de dato por `Float`

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tenia es que en mi función los valores los estaba recibiendo de tipo `numeric`, tuve que cambiar los valores a tipo `float` y en java enviarle de igual manera tipo `float` con esto se soluciono mi problema

El codigo usado en la funcion fue:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.sp_ins_act_productounidad(
_prod_cod character varying,
_uni_codigo integer,
_pu_minimo double precision,
_pu_maximo double precision,
_pu_precionormal double precision,
_pu_precioespecial double precision)
```

Al declarar la función y guardarla el valor de `float` se cambia por `double precision`.

En java lo siguiente:

```
preStmt=con.prepareStatement("SELECT sp_ins_act_productounidad(?,?,?,?,?,?);");
preStmt.setString(1, entPU.getProd_cod());
preStmt.setInt(2, entPU.getUni_codigo());
preStmt.setFloat(3, entPU.getPu_minimo());
preStmt.setFloat(4, entPU.getPu_maximo());
preStmt.setFloat(5, entPU.getPu_precionormal());
preStmt.setFloat(6, entPU.getPu_precioespecial());
rs=preStmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Hola Leo, me alegra que resolvieras tu propia pregunta. ¿Podrías poner el código que utilizaste al final? (para completar un poco esta respuesta)